# number of independent solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How many linearly independent solution does $$x^2y''-xy'+(x^2-y)y=0$$ have? 
My answer is none since independent solutions are valid only for linear differential equations. Am I right? This is just my hunch but I need proof but I don't know how.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you have a solution $y_1$ and $y_2$ and then try the solution $\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$ and see if you can reduce?

Comment: do you mean I have to solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$? Non-linear DE is already beyond my knowledge. This is just a Multiple-choice question I came across in a book. Anyway, is it possible to transform the given DE to linear one? I have tried but to no avail.

Comment: no, I mean use the ansatz that $$x^2y_1'' - xy_1' + (x^2-y_1)y_1 = 0,\\x^2y_2'' - xy_2' + (x^2-y_2)y_2 = 0$$ and then try to use a combination of $y_1,y_2$ to see if a linear combination satisfies the original equation..though looking again it may be that you want to determine if two unique solutions exist, and are linearly independent of one another?

Comment: okay..thanks i'm working on it.